# Find the columns names and datatypes from an SQL query in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

How can I get the column names and datatypes in Laravel 8 from a select query result set (not table)?

I have the following statement:

```
$report = Report::findOrFail($id);

$results = DB::connection($report->db)
                ->select($report->query, (array) $params_with_values);
```

The `$report->query` is an SQL Query and after is executed with the passing parameters `$params_with_values` returns a result dataset from SQL with it's column names.

e.g.

```
select e.first_name,e.last_name,s.salary 
       from employees e 
            inner join salaries s on s.emp_id = e.id;
```

I need to get only the **column names** and their **datatypes** even if the query doesn't return any result. For the example above should be:

```
FIRST_NAME:VARCHAR, 
LAST_NAME:VARCHAR, 
SALARY: NUMBER
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
Route::get('showTablesWithDataTypes',function(){
   return collect(DB::select('describe users'))->map(function ($item, $key) {
       return [
           'columnName' => $item->Field,
           'columnType' => $item->Type,
       ];
   });
});
```

Output

```
    [
  {
    "columnName": "id",
    "columnType": "bigint(20) unsigned"
  },
  {
    "columnName": "name",
    "columnType": "varchar(255)"
  },
  {
    "columnName": "email",
    "columnType": "varchar(255)"
  },
  {
    "columnName": "email_verified_at",
    "columnType": "timestamp"
  },
  {
    "columnName": "password",
    "columnType": "varchar(255)"
  },
  {
    "columnName": "remember_token",
    "columnType": "varchar(100)"
  },
  {
    "columnName": "created_at",
    "columnType": "timestamp"
  },
  {
    "columnName": "updated_at",
    "columnType": "timestamp"
  }
]
```

Comment: Hello Vipertecpro. I need to list the fields of the SQL Statement... Not to describe a table.

Comment: No idea what you are trying to say please rephrase your question.

Comment: I have updated the initial request and make it more clear. I want the fields (names & types) from the result set of an SQL Query... Not the table, but the result set.